Getting error ("The requested FontFamily could not be found") while trying to run exe file through Wine
Lenovo Lenovo V14-ADA
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
wine-6.0.3 (Ubuntu 6.0.3~repack-1)
I'm trying to install DeepL application (.exe file),
this is what I get:
wine DeepLSetup.exe 
exception inside UnhandledException handler: (null) assembly:C:\windows\mono\mon
o-2.0\lib\mono\4.5\mscorlib.dll type:ArgumentException member:(null)

[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentException: The requested FontFamily could not be found [GDI+ status: FontFamilyNotFound]
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus.CheckStatus (System.Drawing.Status status) [0x001ce] in <fc2ea6474c6d4315858618f13de6e72a>:0 
  at System.Drawing.FontFamily..ctor (System.Drawing.Text.GenericFontFamilies genericFamily) [0x0004d] in <fc2ea6474c6d4315858618f13de6e72a>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.FontFamily..ctor(System.Drawing.Text.GenericFontFamilies)
  at System.Drawing.FontFamily.get_GenericSansSerif () [0x00000] in <fc2ea6474c6d4315858618f13de6e72a>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Font.CreateFont (System.String familyName, System.Single emSize, System.Drawing.FontStyle style, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit unit, System.Byte charSet, System.Boolean isVertical) [0x00011] in <fc2ea6474c6d4315858618f13de6e72a>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Font..ctor (System.String familyName, System.Single emSize, System.Drawing.FontStyle style, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit unit, System.Byte gdiCharSet, System.Boolean gdiVerticalFont) [0x00011] in <fc2ea6474c6d4315858618f13de6e72a>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Font..ctor (System.String familyName, System.Single emSize, System.String systemName) [0x00000] in <fc2ea6474c6d4315858618f13de6e72a>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.Font..ctor(string,single,string)
  at System.Drawing.SystemFonts.get_DefaultFont () [0x00000] in <fc2ea6474c6d4315858618f13de6e72a>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_DefaultFont () [0x0000e] in <d22f8be2dd674c49bd49b314423240b8>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.GetDefaultFontHandleWrapper () [0x0000e] in <d22f8be2dd674c49bd49b314423240b8>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_FontHandle () [0x00149] in <d22f8be2dd674c49bd49b314423240b8>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetWindowFont () [0x00001] in <d22f8be2dd674c49bd49b314423240b8>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnHandleCreated (System.EventArgs e) [0x00020] in <d22f8be2dd674c49bd49b314423240b8>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar.OnHandleCreated (System.EventArgs e) [0x00001] in <d22f8be2dd674c49bd49b314423240b8>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x0002c] in <d22f8be2dd674c49bd49b314423240b8>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x004ce] in <d22f8be2dd674c49bd49b314423240b8>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00001] in <d22f8be2dd674c49bd49b314423240b8>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x000b3] in <d22f8be2dd674c49bd49b314423240b8>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00025] in <d22f8be2dd674c49bd49b314423240b8>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.Windows.Forms.Message&)
  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindowProc.Callback (System.IntPtr hWnd, System.Int32 msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) [0x0002a] in <d22f8be2dd674c49bd49b314423240b8>:0 
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindowProc.Callback(intptr,int,intptr,intptr)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IntCreateWindowEx(int,string,string,int,int,int,int,int,System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef,System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef,System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef,object)
  at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CreateWindowEx (System.Int32 dwExStyle, System.String lpszClassName, System.String lpszWindowName, System.Int32 style, System.Int32 x, System.Int32 y, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef hWndParent, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef hMenu, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef hInst, System.Object pvParam) [0x00001] in <d22f8be2dd674c49bd49b314423240b8>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle (System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams cp) [0x0010b] in <d22f8be2dd674c49bd49b314423240b8>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle () [0x0014f] in <d22f8be2dd674c49bd49b314423240b8>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar.CreateHandle () [0x00039] in <d22f8be2dd674c49bd49b314423240b8>:0 
  at NanoByte.Common.Controls.TaskProgressBar..ctor () [0x00006] in <fea567bd35ee4bdfb2fd1f7228937c3c>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) NanoByte.Common.Controls.TaskProgressBar..ctor()
  at NanoByte.Common.Controls.TaskControl.InitializeComponent () [0x0000b] in <fea567bd35ee4bdfb2fd1f7228937c3c>:0 
  at NanoByte.Common.Controls.TaskControl..ctor () [0x00006] in <fea567bd35ee4bdfb2fd1f7228937c3c>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) NanoByte.Common.Controls.TaskControl..ctor()
  at ZeroInstall.MainForm.InitializeComponent () [0x0000b] in <fea567bd35ee4bdfb2fd1f7228937c3c>:0 
  at ZeroInstall.MainForm..ctor (System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource) [0x00018] in <fea567bd35ee4bdfb2fd1f7228937c3c>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) ZeroInstall.MainForm..ctor(System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource)
  at ZeroInstall.GuiBootstrapHandler.<.ctor>b__1_0 () [0x00006] in <fea567bd35ee4bdfb2fd1f7228937c3c>:0 
  at NanoByte.Common.Threading.AsyncFormWrapper`1+<>c__DisplayClass1_1[T].<.ctor>b__1 () [0x00000] in <fea567bd35ee4bdfb2fd1f7228937c3c>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at NanoByte.Common.ExceptionUtils.Rethrow (System.Exception exception) [0x00014] in <fea567bd35ee4bdfb2fd1f7228937c3c>:0 
  at NanoByte.Common.ExceptionUtils.RethrowFirstInner (System.AggregateException exception) [0x0008a] in <fea567bd35ee4bdfb2fd1f7228937c3c>:0 
  at NanoByte.Common.Threading.AsyncFormWrapper`1+<>c__DisplayClass1_0[T].<.ctor>b__0 () [0x00054] in <fea567bd35ee4bdfb2fd1f7228937c3c>:0 
  at System.Lazy`1[T].ViaFactory (System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode mode) [0x00043] in <e70d6e9587d64cb3abb4b3f99bbf5a0d>:0 
  at System.Lazy`1[T].ExecutionAndPublication (System.LazyHelper executionAndPublication, System.Boolean useDefaultConstructor) [0x00022] in <e70d6e9587d64cb3abb4b3f99bbf5a0d>:0 
  at System.Lazy`1[T].CreateValue () [0x00074] in <e70d6e9587d64cb3abb4b3f99bbf5a0d>:0 
  at System.Lazy`1[T].get_Value () [0x0000a] in <e70d6e9587d64cb3abb4b3f99bbf5a0d>:0 
  at NanoByte.Common.Threading.AsyncFormWrapper`1[T].Post[TResult] (System.Func`2[T,TResult] action) [0x00000] in <fea567bd35ee4bdfb2fd1f7228937c3c>:0 
  at ZeroInstall.GuiBootstrapHandler.GetCustomStorePath (System.Boolean machineWide, System.String currentPath) [0x00023] in <fea567bd35ee4bdfb2fd1f7228937c3c>:0 
  at ZeroInstall.BootstrapProcess.CustomizeStorePath () [0x00040] in <fea567bd35ee4bdfb2fd1f7228937c3c>:0 
  at ZeroInstall.BootstrapProcess.Execute (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] args) [0x00046] in <fea567bd35ee4bdfb2fd1f7228937c3c>:0 
  at ZeroInstall.ProgramUtils.Run (System.String[] args, ZeroInstall.IBootstrapHandler handler) [0x00028] in <fea567bd35ee4bdfb2fd1f7228937c3c>:0 


Check with https://www.winehq.org. Not all Windows programs are available through wine. This is not a Ubuntu problem, this is a wine problem.
